# Increment integer before using as text for widget

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, widget, settext

I've a weird problem when I try to set the text in GWT Widget (My ide is Eclipse Juno).

Here the case:
I've a class with a getter that returns an integer
    int myClass.getValue();
I want use this value incremented by 1 to set the text in a widget, 
I've tried in several way without find out a solution:

```
myWidget.setText(""+1+myClass.getValue());
myWidget.setText(""+(int)(1+myClass.getValue()));
myWidget.setText(Integer.toString(1+myClass.getValue()));
.
.
.
```

After the compilation in the resulting webapp the text is always""

```
1value
```

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I'm trying from some time and I didn't figured out :(

Comment: That is very odd. Have you tried putting the `1+myClass.getValue()` as a local variable and then `setText(""+localVariable)`?

Comment: Agreed, this is bizarre.  Only the first example should be giving that kind of result - given the parenthesis/function call, you should be getting the incremented versions in the other instances.  Personally, I prefer the third version in most instances (for one thing, there may be cached strings for certain values, starting with -1, 0, 1, 10.... The integer class usually caches instances of the wrapper class up to 100, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
myWidgetsetText(Integer.toString(1+getValue()));
```

Comment: setText argument is a String :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
I don't know why other ways don't work (I'm pretty sure that in the past some did work for me), but at the end I've used this trick:

Somewhere

```
public static int incrementByOne(int value)
{
    int result = value;
    result++;
    return result;
}
```

then:

```
myWidget.setText(""+Somewhere.incrementByOne(myClass.getValue()));
```

LOL, a simplest solution:

```
myWidget.setText(myClass.getValue()-(-1));
```